# How do you reverse the order of the elements in a queue using one additional queue,no other collection, possibly some variables in JAVA?

Tags: java, queue, reverse

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Maybe its the fact I have only had two hours of sleep...I dunno.

I got my pseudocode to reverse the items of up to three elements inside of a queue, but after three, I draw a blank.

Pseudocode is preferred as I'm just learning about this stuff.

Comment: Is this homework? An interview question?

Comment: It's not necessarily homework. Trying to learn this using a book I just bought and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be easier with a stack but with two queues can be:

```
q1; --full
q2; --empty

while(not q1.isEmpty()){
if(q1.lenght()!=1){ 
  for(int i = 0; i <= q1.lenght() - 1; ++i){
     q1.push(q1.pop());
  } 
}
 q2.push(q1.pop());
}
```